# whenever I start my windows laptop, after laptop is opened terminal is automatically opened and inside terminal its written -

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

```
unable to open "C:\Users\98298\AppData\Roaming\Dll\config.json".
unable to open "C:\Users\98298\.xmrig.json".
unable to open "C:\Users\98298\.config\xmrig.json".
```

I'm not sure what is causing problem? Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your computer is (or was) infected with crypto miner [XMRig](https://xmrig.com/). The best you can do is to reinstall your OS from clean copy and restore your important files from backup.

Comment: Even if the computer was infected by a virus, reinstalling the OS isn't the single option, it can mostly be cleaned (some info https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit). But XMRig isn't even a real virus, so it can certainly be removed.

Comment: @YisroelTech, generally speaking you can't be sure some malware do not use it.

Comment: True. But **1)** there is no basis here for suspecting malware (at least beyond simply installing XMRig) **2)** even with malware reinstalling an OS is really drastic and typically not needed

Comment: @YisroelTech, there are too many if's and I will prefer to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

that startup terminal saying unable to open i just fixed it by going to task manager then go to startup then find "VScan" google says it is disguise as a windows core but it's not, u can disable that or click that then open file location then delete it. Now the startup terminal is no longer my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is what I did to fix this problem. Go to your windows defender and scan for viruses, you shouldn't get any result but guess what, the virus has excluded the AppData folder from being scanned. so make sure you unselect that exclusion. Scan again and you will find out that that they have infected some of the files. Remove them automatically through windows defender. Restart and it shall be fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-windows-terminal-settings/31424a04-bd9d-4e83-b2b7-02c80dfda9ee

its happened in windows 11.
this microsoft link help you solve this problem . or go to microsoft help desk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155826)

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9OWv.png)Run "Microsoft defender antivirus(Offline scan)"
From 'scan options' in 'Virus &threat protection'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160561)