# On windows startup terminal opens automatically and showing file not found error

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-11

I am using Windows 11. Every time I boot my computer the terminal opens automatically and show some error that some file not found.

```
[2022-07-26 21:33:19.746] unable to open "C:\Users\Hridoy\AppData\Roaming\Dll\config.json".
[2022-07-26 21:33:19.959] unable to open "C:\Users\Hridoy\.xmrig.json".
[2022-07-26 21:33:20.184] unable to open "C:\Users\Hridoy\.config\xmrig.json".

[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
```

[image]

Startup programs from task manager:

[image]

What is the cause for this? And should I be worried? And how can I fix this?

I found another question on superuser: [whenever I start my windows laptop, after laptop is opened terminal is automatically opened and inside terminal its written -](https://superuser.com/questions/1733699/whenever-i-start-my-windows-laptop-after-laptop-is-opened-terminal-is-automatic)
but that question does not have any solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I am looking for a solution without reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Even though the linked duplicate does not have an answer, we only need one of these questions, and these are clearly the same question. This question should remain closed and answers made on the other.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the name of the files this is from the **XMRig CPU Miner** prgroam. This is a Crypto Minor program (https://xmrig.com/).

But if you didn't install it ever, it might've been maliciously installed on your computer by malware. (For general info on malware scanning and removal, see [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)).

For this specifically, the best would be to:

1. Check the ***Settings*** > ***Apps*** > ***Apps & feature*** list if you find a program named **XMRig**, and if so uninstall it
2. In the ***Task Manager*** go to the ***Startup*** tab and see if there is anything there you don't recognize. If there is you can right-click and **Disable** it (you can add a screenshot of the ***Task Manager*** go to the ***Startup*** tab to your question for others to be able to review)

Comment: I have added the startup program image with my question.

Answer (score 1):

This message is displayed because of [XMRig](https://xmrig.com/docs/miner),
described as a CPU/GPU miner and RandomX benchmark, searching for
the file `xmrig.json` and others.

You have perhaps removed XMRig and this is just a leftover.

Use
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
and search for the string "XMRig" inside the Everything tab.

Once you find it, then delete it.

Comment: I have searched and didn't found anything as `xmrig` with the autoruns program inside everything tab.